# Is there a .gitkeep equivalent for Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

What is the preferred way to keep empty folders included in the working tree that is under hg management? I have never seen a Mercurial repo with .hgkeep files in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But in git, you simply add any empty file which make git reference the folder.

I would rather use `.keep` than `.gitkeep`, and so I'd say the same should apply to Mercurial ?

Comment: Yes, I've seen `.keep` files being used for this in Mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

`.gitkeep` is not a special name to Git.  It's just a convention.  You could use `.gitkeep` as the placeholder filename in Mercurial too if you wanted!  Myself, I use README files and inside I write a note explaining why the directory needs to be checked in if it's empty.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your style. Have you seen anyone else use this method? The reason I'm asking about a convention is because I'm lazy and want to use something that is least effort for me, but not confusing to others cloning the project.

Comment: I have seen people writing README files since at least the 1980's.  Obviously not for this exact purpose, but I can't think of a more clear way to document an empty directory than putting a document right inside it!  A .keep file would be my choice only if it were for some reason mandatory to have the file be hidden--even then I would probably use .README so that I could explain to newcomers why there is an empty directory there.

Answer (score 2):

Neither git nor hg track folders, only files. So if you require an 'empty' folder to be present you have to track a file within it, as it were. The file would otherwise be ignored by you, and can be called anything you like.

Comment: I know. I was hoping there was a generally accepted convention like the git-folk seem to have. That way people cloning the project don't need a lot of explanation.

Comment: There isn't a convention in hg AFAIK. FWIW we use .ignore.